# How can I using get_sentences() on an excel file in R?

Tags: r, excel, text

This is the given example of sentiment analysis.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ir41.png)
Now I want to import an excel file and using the same function get_sentences here, how to deal with this error?
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mn76M.png)
[hexcel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfJf8.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I have enough info to be of help, but since it wants data to be character I'd first try seeing it `as.character(data)` instead of data works. If data is more than one columns perhaps testing it out on one column could narrow your problem if it persists

Comment: Are there any ways to select specific columns and rows as the new dataset? I mean, for example, I wanna extract 'negative' column and rows 2-10 as a new data negative_training, how to write this code?

Comment: Oh I found how to do that. Thanks for help.